# Django Admin TypeError args[0] = str(args[0]), cannot update or delete objects

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

```
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1 [2020-06-05 01:21:24 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Error handling request /admin/parts_table/part/35/change/
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1 Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = self.get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
......
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     response = response.render()
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     self.content = self.rendered_content
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return template.render(context, self._request)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.template.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self._render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.nodelist.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return compiled_parent._render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.nodelist.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return compiled_parent._render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.nodelist.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return nodelist.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return nodelist.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 986, in render
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 697, in resolve
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 42, in _dec
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1     args[0] = str(args[0])
Jun 04 18:21:25 dev-strandbase app/web.1 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm getting a strange TypeError (above) after making some changes to my model. I cant find any results on how to deal with this anywhere. I get the same error when i click to delete an object or update an object, and I get the same TypeError (but with a different preceeding error log) when I update/delete objects which use the "parts" model as a foreign key.

Here's the error log for a different page that calls the same model

````
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response or self.get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = get_response(request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     response = response.render()
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     self.content = self.rendered_content
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 696, in get_context
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 511, in get_rendered_html_form
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 521, in render_form_for_serializer
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     {'style': {'template_pack': 'rest_framework/horizontal'}}
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 372, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return template.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.template.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self._render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.nodelist.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return nodelist.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 87, in render_field
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return renderer.render_field(field, style)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 351, in render_field
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return template.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.template.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self._render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.nodelist.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return self.render(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 161, in render
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     values = self.sequence.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     obj = self.var.resolve(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 857, in _resolve_lookup
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     current = current()
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 215, in iter_options
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in get_choices
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     for item in queryset
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in <listcomp>
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     for item in queryset
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 221, in display_value
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1     return str(instance)
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Jun 05 16:41:04 production-strandbase app/web.1 10.16.190.48 - - [05/Jun/2020:23:41:04 +0000] "GET /api/partfeatures/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"```
````

Comment: it seems you do `str = ...` so now you have variable `str` and it can't access function `str()`. You have to find where you use `str = ...` and use different name for variable.

Comment: that was my first thought -- but it doesn't look like I'm using str anywhere.

Comment: error shows many paths to `...\template\...` - maybe you use `str` in some template or you use `str` as key with dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Figured it out. If anyone else comes across this, I realized the issue was I was using the @property decorator for the def **str** function in my model. I fixed that and the rest worked.